# VB.Net Excel class create but individual sheets

Tags: vb.net

Thank you in advance. I am very new to coding and have stumbled across a slight problem. 
I have created a windows form that fills in an Excel sheet in the back ground for various reports. I have created the class but now cannot figure out how to get the worksheet per individual form. 
This is my original code and it worked perfectly when used for a single form.

```
    Dim iExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim iBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim iSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    iExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    iExcel.Visible = True
    iBook = iExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\.....")
    iSheet = iBook.Worksheets("Lifts")
```

But by creating a Class I cannot figure out how to call the individual sheet in the instance. 
This is my new code with the class

```
    Dim excelNew As ExcelOpen = New ExcelOpen()
    excelNew.OpenExcel()
```

excelNew.OpenExcel() opens the workbook but I need it to be on the right sheet.
But how do I call the specific sheet for individual forms in this case Engineering instead of Lifts?

Comment: Where is the code for the `ExcelOpen` class?  We can't see what it does so it is near on impossible to answer your question.  Where are you using this class?  You really need to post your full code to get a clear idea.

Comment: Also, is this VB/VBA or VB.NET?  Code is slightly different for each language.  BTW, `CreatObject` is misspelled.

Comment: It says VB.net in the subject

Comment: Then why are have you tagged it with vba and excel-vba?

Comment: Are you going to help or just point out mistakes?

Comment: Pointing out your mistake IS helping you - your attitude isn't.  I have already suggested posting your complete code block before I can assist you properly and you haven't done it

Comment: Well I just need to know how to call an individual sheet by using the class. The first bit of code already does that but only if I write it into every form. I created the class to so that I can just call the class instead of writing all the code again. But cannot write the call sheet into it because everyone differs.

Comment: This is my point. I need to see what is in your class.  Have you passed in a reference to Excel?  You can use a variable for the sheet name, it doesn't have to be a literal.  It all depends on the structure of your class, how you instantiate it and the properties you maintaining.

Comment: Posting enough code to give readers a clear, complete picture of the situation without drowning them in irrelevant procedures can be a fine line to walk. You posted enough that I *think* I understand your question and answered accordingly, but 1) I could be wrong, and 2) even if I wasn't, I could have better tailored the answer to your needs if I had seen the code for your class. So do your best when posting a question but always add additional code when requested. This, along with other site conventions such as using tags correctly, will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code you posted, here is what I think you are looking for:

```
Public Class ExcelOpen

    Private sheetName As String

    Public Sub New(Optional ByVal wsName As String = "Sheet1")
        sheetName = wsName
    End Sub

    Public Sub OpenExcel()
        Dim iExcel As Excel.Application
        Dim iBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim iSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        iExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        iExcel.Visible = True
        iBook = iExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\.....")
        iSheet = iBook.Worksheets(sheetName)
    End Sub

End Class

Dim excelNew As ExcelOpen = New ExcelOpen("Engineering")
excelNew.OpenExcel()
```

Comment: Josh sorry for the late reply. That did not work unfortunately.

Comment: In the class is exactly what you (Josh) posted on your reply. But I cannot specify the sheet name in the class as it is something that each form will have that uses the class and called from there.

Comment: The sheet name in the class I provided is a *variable*. You pass the sheet name you want each time you create a new instance of the class, as in the last two lines. You don't have to use a literal value (e.g. "Engineering"); you can use a variable such as `Dim excelNew As ExcelOpen = New ExcelOpen(textSheetName.Text)`.